# While creating table in oracle database it is showing right parenthesis missing error

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

While creating table in oracle database it is showing right parenthesis missing error

```
CREATE TABLE Catalog(
sid VARCHAR2(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Suppliers(sid),
pid VARCHAR2(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Parts(pid),
quantity VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

Comment: Do the `Suppliers` and `Parts` tables already exist?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the parts `FOREIGN KEY` as :

```
CREATE TABLE Catalog(
sid VARCHAR2(50) REFERENCES Suppliers(sid),
pid VARCHAR2(50) REFERENCES Parts(pid),
quantity VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

or you may create as :

```
CREATE TABLE Catalog
( sid VARCHAR2(50),
  pid VARCHAR2(50),
  quantity VARCHAR2(50),
    CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
    FOREIGN KEY (sid)
    REFERENCES suppliers(sid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_parts
    FOREIGN KEY (pid)
    REFERENCES parts(pid)    
);
```

by defining `FOREIGN CONSTRAINTS`' names

or if the table already has been created before, by the following way, the constraints may be added later :

```
CREATE TABLE Catalog
( sid VARCHAR2(50),
  pid VARCHAR2(50),
  quantity VARCHAR2(50)  
);

ALTER TABLE Catalog
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
  FOREIGN KEY (sid)
  REFERENCES suppliers(sid);

ALTER TABLE Catalog
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_parts
  FOREIGN KEY (pid)
  REFERENCES parts(pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraint syntax is [documented here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm).

***inline_constraint::=***
[image: inline_constraint]

***out_of_line_constraint::=***
[image: out_of_line_constraint]

***references_clause::=***
[image]

Your examples are **inline**, as they are part of the column definition rather than in a separate section or statement.

I would write it as:

```
create table catalog
( sid       references suppliers(sid)
, pid       references parts(pid)
, quantity  varchar2(50) );
```

or if I wanted to name them explicitly:

```
create table catalog
( sid       constraint cat_supplier_fk references suppliers(sid)
, pid       constraint cat_part_fk references parts(pid)
, quantity  varchar2(50) );
```

You can explicitly override the default datatype if you want, but I consider it better practice to allow it to inherit from the parent. (You can only do this with inline constraints.)